# How to store Google Map markers using cloud storage (Android Studio)?

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Here is what I want to do. To preface I am using Java in Android Studio and the Google Maps API.

- User makes marker (done)
- User adds name for marker (done)
- This marker is stored so everyone who has the app can see it on their map (what I need help on)

Since this is just a little side project I am wondering what the best online storage method/ tool is for this. I would also prefer the tool to be free.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the storage which you need only for your app, you can just host a simple website and store a JSON file on it.

Anytime a person adds a new marker, you can upload the latitude, longitude coordinates, and titles to your JSON 'database'.

Then, anytime a person uses your app it should load the JSON file which contains the latitude, longitude and the titles of all the markers your users have set in history.

Then, your app should read all this data and set markers accordingly.

There are other options also, but this is the cheapest (as websites can be hosted for free ) and also this is easiest to implement (just open the connection to the URL and work with JSON).